# Why is this Flutter FilteringTextInputFormatter regex not working?

Tags: regex, flutter, textfield

On a Flutter `TextField` I have the following `FilteringTextInputFormatter`:

`FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"^\d+\.?\d{1,2}"));`

It tries to match a decimal number up to two places, but I can't input any numbers into the `TextField`.

https://regexr.com/7fpho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing with RegExr, I found that what I wanted was:

`RegExp(r"^\d{1,4}(\.\d{0,2})?")`

This expression allows four digits with two decimal places.

Comment: But, it also allows an X on the end.  You have no end anchor now.  And any attempt to add an end anchor will fail when you have a dot with no digits following it.  My general advice is to avoid filtering regex.  Use only a validation regex.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
                                    TextField(
                                      keyboardType: const TextInputType
                                          .numberWithOptions(
                                        decimal: true,
                                      ),
                                      inputFormatters: [
                                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                          RegExp(r'^\d*\.?\d{0,2}'),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
```

Comment: this solutions works for me. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Do not filter based on a regex that targets the entire string when finished.  Remember that to type "hello world", at some point you must type "hello" and a single space, so your regex that demands no space at the end will fail in a filter.

Instead, use a regex match in the final validation.  Not in the filter.

Comment: Ah, ok I see why it would fail cause it fails to match just 1 number. Thanks.